# How to debug Node with Grunt from webstorm

Tags: node.js, debugging, gruntjs, webstorm

I have been using grunt in my project and I wanted to be able to debug the code using web storm.

1. How do I open a debug port in node JS? 
   When trying to use the remote debug a nodeJS option the IDE hangs on trying to debug...
2. When trying to control node from within webstorm I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043484/grunt-debugging-from-webstorm) question
   I am getting: 
   \nodejs\node.exe \grunt server

Process finished with exit code 99.

Any ideas?[image: Here is my run/debug configuration panel]

Comment: what are you trying to debug - static files served by Grunt static server (server task)? Or? Running Grunt with server taks using the configuration from your screenshot works fine for me (note that I'm using grunt-contrib-connect instead of server task), and I can debug static files served on this server using the javascript debug run configuration

Comment: No, I just press on Run button "the green arrow" to start the server and I am getting the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: hmm... and what happens when you execute 'node C:\Users\jay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt server' in the command line from your project directory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233279/how-to-debug-grunt-in-phpstorm-webstorm

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 'server' application parameter.