# Node.js server debuging with WebStorm (grunt)

Tags: node.js, debugging, gruntjs, webstorm

I'm using grunt to launch my server with livereload and other tasks.
I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043484/grunt-debugging-from-webstorm?rq=1) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233279/how-to-debug-grunt-in-phpstorm-webstorm) to run my grunt tasks.
It's working but I can't debug properly (when I set some breakpoints, there aren't hit)

When I launch the script, here is what I got:
[image]

As you can see the debugger appears in a 2nd tab, but it's not doing anything. (even if it says it's connected successfully).
To debug my app I've to stop this 2nd tab, and run a remote debugger... Anyway to fix this?

Additional info: The server is run in another process. If I run it in the same process as grunt, there are no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by lena, the issue seems to be fixed in [WebStorm 8](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11140).

Answer (score 0):

What Node.js version do you use? In 0.10.x the child process occupies the same port as a master process, so debugging won't work by default. Related ticket: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5318. Can you check if it works for you using Node.js ersion >= 0.11.4? Also, what Grunt tasks are being used?

Comment: I've upgrated to node 0.11.11 and have still the same issue. However I've found a fix. I was using grunt-express-server to launch my server  (with the --debug option). Modifying the task source code and replacing --debug by --debug-brk fixed the issue :)
Link of the issue: https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-express-server/issues/44

Comment: this is exactly what I did - see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957411/debugging-grunt-with-intellij

Comment: Thanks for the issue number!

Comment: FYI: [WEB-11140](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11140) is fixed in WebStorm8